# Convert formatted time (HH:mm) to integer using dayjs

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I am currently using the dayjs library and I am currently trying to convert a formatted time, such as `'02:00'` to an integer that represents the total minutes.  In this case it would 120.  I am trying to use dayjs duration plugin, but it appears the following does not work without passing in an integer.  My code is as follows:

```
dayjs.duration('02:00').asMinutes()
```

this however returns NaN.  If anyone is familiar with the dayjs library I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `'02:00'` is ambigious.  Is it minutes and seconds?  Or hours and minutes?  That's why they don't accept a single string as a parameter unless its in a specific format.  See [the docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/durations/creating)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this result.  I'm assuming for duration dayjs will only accept an integer then

Comment: Correct, it only accepts an integer. You will need to parse your string according to whatever logic you want before passing the integer to the function. As an outsider, I also don't know if that's two hours or two minutes, how does your program know that? From there just parse the string as an int, multiply by some constant, and pass that to `duration()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to process your data, perhaps with regex. Duration does accept an object with explicit labels though to make this operation a bit easier.

https://day.js.org/docs/en/durations/creating

```js
const timeString = "2:00";
const h = timeString.match(/(\d{1,2}):\d+/)[1];
const hInt = parseInt(h);
console.log("Hours: " + hInt)

const m = timeString.match(/\d{1,2}:(\d+)/)[1];
const mInt = parseInt(m);
console.log("Minutes: " + mInt);

// dayjs.duration({ hours: hInt, minutes: mInt })
```

EDIT: Per Amy's, this is more efficient and simpler:

```js
const [h, m] = "2:00".split(":").map( val => parseInt(val) );
console.log("Hours: " + h)
console.log("Minutes: " + m);

// dayjs.duration({ hours: h, minutes: m})
```

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to simply split on the `:`:   `var [h, m] = '02:00'.split(':')`.

Comment: Yes, that is better :)

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem. And wanted to use dayjs too, instead of **moment()** library.

But in wiki for **dayjs-duration** mentioned - it's not possible. They are suggesting to use diff as middle step.
[image: dayjs duration]

If you want to use solution **based on dayjs only**.

```
const myDay = dayjs("05:30am", "hh:mma")
const diff = myDay.diff(myDay.startOf('day'))
const dayTimeStartMinutes = dayjs.duration(diff, 'milliseconds').asMinutes() // or asHours(), asDays(), ...
// result 
// dayTimeStartMinutes = 350
```